# Redirect Process Output to JSON

Tags: c#, json

I'm attempting to capture the result from a vswhere command in JSON.  When I run the command `vswhere -legacy -format json` directly in the command line I get the following formatted JSON:

```json
[
    {
        "instanceId":"828a2470",
        "installDate":"2020-11-12T15:38:31Z",
        "installationName":"VisualStudio/16.8.3+30804.86",
        "installationPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Enterprise",
        "installationVersion":"16.8.30804.86",
        "productId":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Enterprise",
        "productPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Enterprise\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe",
        "state":4294967295,
        "isComplete":true,
        "isLaunchable":true,
        "isPrerelease":false,
...
    }
]
```

When I attempt to capture that data in my c# application, I get the following plain text:

```
Visual Studio Locator version 2.8.4+ff0de50053 [query version 2.7.3111.17308]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

instanceId: 828a2470
installDate: 11/12/2020 10:38:31 AM
installationName: VisualStudio/16.8.3+30804.86
installationPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise
installationVersion: 16.8.30804.86
productId: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Enterprise
productPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
state: 4294967295
isComplete: 1
isLaunchable: 1
isPrerelease: 0
...
```

This is not valid JSON and so I cannot parse it.  How can I retrieve the JSON in my code the way I see it in the console?

Here's the code:

```
var cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
            "vswhere.exe");
                cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
         cmd.Start();

        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("vswhere -legacy -format json");
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        cmd.WaitForExit();

        var result = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply run the following program, without writing to standard input and using the Arguments, you can get the output you want.

```
var cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "-legacy -format json";
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.Start();

cmd.WaitForExit();

string result = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
cmd.Dispose();

// result holds the json that can be deserialized.

// One way to deserialize is this.. but you can create a POCO if you'd be doing this alot.
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(result);
Console.WriteLine(obj[0].instanceId);

// prints
  828a2470
```

Note: you are getting the simple text because you are executing the actual executable without any arguments. You have to use `StartInfo.Arguments` to pass the arguments to the executable... not `StandardInput.WriteLine`.

Comment: Thank you!  I could not understand why the JSON was not being captured...in fact many hours worth of not understanding.